# selected area is empty , delete middle image using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i have an image and i want to remove a piece of the middle to make the overall image smaller width.

when i select there and want use (CTRL+X) or (DELETE) says : could not compelete becasue selected area is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error when you try to delete something from an area of a layer that has nothing in it. Make sure you have the correct layer selected then try again.